# Combining bootstrap navbar and CSS grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, css-grid

Can the navigation bar for a website be created with bootstrap and everything below that styled with CSS Grid? Would this mess up the grid at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap will only affect the elements that contain the classes and IDs in the class. If you create a page with navigation in bootstrap and with your own CSS without using these elements, there will be no problem.